# Does AWS Eventbridge API Destination accept request body with POST/PUT Action Method

Tags: amazon-web-services, post, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to build an API Destination in AWS Eventbridge that should hit a POST endpoint into our system. Request handler in the system expects request body also. So, is there any way to attach request body in AWS Eventbridge API Destnations?
***I tried to look for this on [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-api-destinations.html), found nothing, so is it a no-go situation?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API destinations are third-party targets outside of AWS that you can invoke with an HTTP request. EventBridge invokes the HTTP endpoint and delivers the event as a payload within the request. You can use any preferred HTTP method, such as GET or POST. You can use input transformers to change the payload format to match your target.
Please refer to the section Customizing the payload

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-destinations-with-amazon-eventbridge/